# I have swagger URL TO TEST in jmeter. How to handle dynamic token generation?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I Have examined the endpoints, but the project is based on a micro-services architecture, i.e. the JWT token or authorization changes severely whenever someone logs on to the server.

So the token I have extracted from the USER CONTROLLE R(Authentication API), when I am passing that token with further requests, it is showing error 401 or authorization failed.

SO what should I do to configure some request sampler that every time when the test runs it fetches the current JWT TOKEN and test runs successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Introduction to JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/) article, the tokens have

> **exp** (expiration time)

I don't think you should be obtaining a new JWT token for each and every request, my expectation is that you need to do this only once, via i.e. [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) and refresh it only if your test duration exceeds the token life span.

You can inspect JWT token attributes using i.e. https://jwt.io/ website

I would also suggest double-checking that the token is properly extracted from the USER CONTROLLER and added to the next request, it can be done using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.